# Query a list LINQ-style in PowerShell

Tags: linq, powershell

```
add-type -Language CSharpVersion3 -TypeDefinition @"
    public class pack_code
    {
        public pack_code() {}

        public string code { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
"@

$a = New-Object pack_code
$a.code = "3"
$a.type = "5"
$b = New-Object pack_code
$b.code = "2"
$b.type = "5"
$c = New-Object pack_code
$c.code = "2"
$c.type = "5"
$d = New-Object pack_code
$d.code = "1"
$d.type = "1"

$codes = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[object]'
$codes.add($a)
$codes.add($b)
$codes.add($c)
$codes.add($d)
```

Is there a way to select distinct from $codes and select the objects where type equals 1? How can I use LINQ with PowerShell?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What Keith said. Plus, changed the constructor in your C# and used the -Unique parameter on the Sort cmdlet.

```
Add-Type -Language CSharpVersion3 -TypeDefinition @"
    public class pack_code
    {
        public pack_code(string code, string type) {
            this.code=code;
            this.type=type;
        }

        public string code { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
"@

$codes = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[object]'
$codes.Add( ( New-Object pack_code 3, 5 ))
$codes.Add( ( New-Object pack_code 2, 5 ))
$codes.Add( ( New-Object pack_code 2, 5 ))
$codes.Add( ( New-Object pack_code 1, 1 ))
$codes.Add( ( New-Object pack_code 2, 2 ))
$codes.Add( ( New-Object pack_code 2, 1 ))
$codes.Add( ( New-Object pack_code 2, 1 ))

$codes | sort code, type -Unique | where {$_.type -eq 1}
```

Answer (score 28):

For distinct use the `Select-Object` cmdlet (aliased to `Select`) with the Unique parameter e.g.:

```
PS> 1,2,3,4,4,2 | Select-Object -Unique
1
2
3
4
```

For filtering use the `Where-Object` cmdlet (aliased to `Where` and `?`):

```
PS> $codes | where {$_.Type -eq '1'}
```

As for LINQ, you can't use LINQ operators in PowerShell because PowerShell doesn't support calling generic .NET methods or static extension methods which are both crucial to LINQ.

<sup>Editor's note: **PSv3+** now ***does* support** those things.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

[Doug Finke's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870231/45375) and [Keith Hill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870134/45375) show you PowerShell-idiomatic analogs to the `.Distinct()` and `.Where()` LINQ methods.

---

In **PowerShell v3 or higher** you now ***can* use LINQ**.

The solution below demonstrates that LINQ can be used to solve your problem, but also shows that doing so is **requires somewhat cumbersome syntax** and is probably **only worth the effort if you need advanced query features and/or performance matters**.

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134048/45375) for a general overview of how to use LINQ from PowerShell.

---

```
# Create the type whose instances will make up the list to filter.
# Make it implement IEquatable<T> with custom comparison logic that
# compares property values so that the .Distinct() LINQ method works correctly.
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"

  public class pack_code : System.IEquatable<pack_code>
  {
      public string code { get; set; }
      public string type { get; set; }

      // IEquatable<T> interface implementation

      // Test equality of this object with another of the same type.
      public bool Equals(pack_code other) {
        // Note: Normally, you'd need to deal with the case of other == null as well.
        return this.code == other.code && this.type == other.type;
      }

      // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
      // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.         
      public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.code.Length + this.type.Length;
      }
  }

"@

# Create the list to filter.
# Note:
#  * Despite not having a constructor for [pack_code], PowerShell is smart
#    enough to construct an instance from a cast from a hashtable that contains
#    entries whose names match the settable [pack_code] properties.
#  * The array of [pack_code] instances is then cast to the list type.
#  * The list contains 3 objects of type 1, but only 2 distinct ones.
$codes = [System.Collections.Generic.List[pack_code]] (
           [pack_code] @{code = '2'; type = '1'},
           [pack_code] @{code = '3'; type = '5'},
           [pack_code] @{code = '2'; type = '1'},
           [pack_code] @{code = '1'; type = '1'}
         )

# Invoke the LINQ methods as static methods of the 
# [System.Linq.Enumerable] type to
# return all distinct objects whose type property is ‘1’.
# Note that the result will be an *iterator*; if you want a
# static array, wrap the call in [Linq.Enumerable]::ToArray(...)
[Linq.Enumerable]::Where(
  [Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct($codes),
  [Func[pack_code, bool]] { $Args[0].type -eq '1' }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

simple question, simple answer :

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct($codes)
```

Comment: That's promising, but as written your code won't work, because it is missing custom comparison logic in order to recognize duplicate `[pack_code]` instances; in other words: your call is an effective no-op.