# Can LINQ be used in PowerShell?

Tags: linq, powershell

I am trying to use LINQ in PowerShell.  It seems like this should be entirely possible since PowerShell is built on top of the .NET Framework, but I cannot get it to work.  For example, when I try the following (contrived) code:

```
$data = 0..10

[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($data, { param($x) $x -gt 5 })
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot find an overload for "Where" and the argument count: "2".

Never mind the fact that this could be accomplished with `Where-Object`.  The point of this question is not to find an idiomatic way of doing this one operation in PowerShell.  Some tasks would be light-years easier to do in PowerShell if I could use LINQ.

Comment: The highest voted answer to this question would suggest that you cannot use LINQ operators in PowerShell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869967/how-to-query-list-in-powershell

Comment: I find it strange that you would say "never mind" to `Where-Object` only to turn around and talk about an "idiomatic" way--`Where-Object` *is* PowerShell's defacto idiomatic way to do it. If you really want LINQ (as opposed to the LINQ-like cmdlets), I would suggest researching binary cmdlets; that way you can hand in the collection and use LINQ where it was meant to be (C# or VB.NET).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The problem with your code is that PowerShell cannot decide to which specific delegate type the `ScriptBlock` instance (`{ ... }`) should be cast. 
So it isn't able to choose a type-concrete delegate instantiation for the generic 2nd parameter of the [`Where` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where). And it also does't have syntax to specify a generic parameter explicitly. To resolve this problem, you need to cast the `ScriptBlock` instance to the right delegate type yourself:

```
$data = 0..10
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($data, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x -gt 5 })
```

> Why does `[Func[object, bool]]` work, but `[Func[int, bool]]` does not?

Because your `$data` is `[object[]]`, not `[int[]]`, given that PowerShell creates `[object[]]` arrays by default; you can, however, construct `[int[]]` instances explicitly:

```
$intdata = [int[]]$data
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($intdata, [Func[int,bool]]{ param($x) $x -gt 5 })
```

Answer (score 56):

To complement [PetSerAl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38361125/45375) with a broader answer to match the question's generic title:

<sup>Note: The following applies up to at least PowerShell 7.3.x *Direct* support for LINQ - with syntax comparable to the one in C# - is being discussed for a *future* version of PowerShell *Core* in [GitHub issue #2226](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2226).</sup>

**Using LINQ in PowerShell**:

- You need **PowerShell v3 or higher**.
- You cannot call the LINQ extension methods directly on collection instances and instead **must invoke the LINQ methods as *static methods* of the [`[System.Linq.Enumerable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable) type** to which you pass the input collection as the first argument.

  - Having to do so **takes away the fluidity of the LINQ API**, because method chaining is no longer an option. Instead, **you must *nest* static calls, in reverse order**.
  - E.g., instead of `$inputCollection.Where(...).OrderBy(...)` you must write `[Linq.Enumerable]::OrderBy([Linq.Enumerable]::Where($inputCollection, ...), ...)`
- **Helper functions and classes:**

  - Some methods, such as `.Select()`, have parameters that accept generic **`Func<>` delegates** (e.g, [`Func<T,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2) can be created using PowerShell code, via a **cast applied to a script block**; e.g.:
    `[Func[object, bool]] { $Args[0].ToString() -eq 'foo' }`

    - The first generic type parameter of `Func<>` delegates must match the type of the elements of the input collection; keep in mind that PowerShell creates `[object[]]` arrays by default.
  - Some methods, such as `.Contains()` and `.OrderBy()` have parameters that accept **objects that implement specific interfaces**, such as `IEqualityComparer<T>` and `IComparer<T>`; additionally, input types may need to implement `IEquatable<T>` in order for comparisons to work as intended, such as with `.Distinct()`; all these **require *compiled classes* written, typically, in C#** (though you can create them from PowerShell by passing a string with embedded C# code to the `Add-Type` cmdlet); in **PSv5+**, however, you **may also use custom [*PowerShell* classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes), with some *limitations***.

    - For *string* operations, specifically, *predefined* classes are available via static properties of the `System.StringComparer` class, which can notably be used to **make string operations case-*insensitive***, to align with PowerShell's own default behavior: [`[StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)<sup>Thanks, [Vopel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11777065/vopel).</sup>
- **Generic methods**:

  - Some LINQ *methods themselves* are generic and therefore require one or more *type arguments*.
  - In **PowerShell (Core) 7.2- and Windows PowerShell**, PowerShell cannot *directly* call such methods and **must use *reflection*** instead, because it only supports *inferring* type arguments, which cannot be done in this case; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Obtain a [string]-instantiated method of OfType<T>.
    $ofTypeString = [Linq.Enumerable].GetMethod("OfType").MakeGenericMethod([string])

    # Output only [string] elements in the collection.
    # Note how the array must be nested for the method signature to be recognized.
    PS> $ofTypeString.Invoke($null, (, ('abc', 12, 'def')))
    abc
    def
    ```

    - For a more elaborate example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569573/45375).
  - In **PowerShell (Core) 7.3+**, you now have the option of **specifying type arguments *explicitly*** (see the conceptual [about_Calling_Generic_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calling_Generic_Methods) help topic); e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Output only [string] elements in the collection.
    # Note the need to enclose the input array in (...)
    # -> 'abc', 'def'
    [Linq.Enumerable]::OfType[string](('abc', 12, 'def'))
    ```
- The **LINQ methods return a *lazy enumerable*** rather than an actual collection; that is, what is returned isn't the actual data yet, but something that will produce the data *when enumerated*.

  - In contexts where enumeration is *automatically* performed, notably in the pipeline, you'll be able to use the enumerable as if it were a collection.

    - However, since the enumerable isn't itself a collection, you cannot get the result count by invoking `.Count` nor can you  *index* into the iterator; however, you can use [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) (extracting the values of a property of the objects being enumerated).
  - If you do **need the results as a static array** to get the usual collection behavior, wrap the invocation in **`[Linq.Enumerable]::ToArray(...)`**.

    - Similar methods that return different data structures exist, such as `::ToList()`.

For an **advanced example**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134102/45375).
For an **overview of all LINQ methods including examples**, see [this great article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/high-performance-powershell-linq/).

---

In short: **using LINQ from PowerShell is cumbersome** and is **only worth the effort if** any of the following apply:

- you need **advanced query features** that PowerShell's cmdlets cannot provide.
- **performance** is paramount - see [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/high-performance-powershell-linq/).

Comment: For methods like Contains and Distinct, if you want to ignore the case of strings, you can use `[StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` (PowerShell operators like -eq use invariant culture) and `[StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase` – these are not to be confused with the enums from the [StringComparison] class, those won't work. It took me a while to figure this out, so hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks, @Vopel - I've added this information to the answer.

Comment: @mkelement0 That was quick! Incidentally, I've experimenting with defining a custom PowerShell class that does the same thing as `[StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to establish a baseline for a more advanced, high-performance comparison function that requires case-insensitivity. Methods like SequenceEqual work correctly, but while I can get the Distinct method to accept my custom class as a parameter, it's still not ignoring the case no matter what I try. I've been trying to implement `IEquatable<T>` as you mentioned. How do you do it in 5.1 without resorting to C# code?

Comment: @Vopel: It should work; perhaps you forgot to override `.GetHashCode()` to ensure that the same hash code is returned for any pair of objects that compare equal? If that doesn't help, I suggest you ask a new question; feel free to ping me here once you have done so.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to achieve LINQ like functionality then PowerShell has some cmdlets and functions, for instance: `Select-Object`, `Where-Object`, `Sort-Object`, `Group-Object`. It has cmdlets for most of LINQ features like Projection, Restriction, Ordering, Grouping, Partitioning, etc.

See [Powershell One-Liners: Collections and LINQ](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-one-liners--collections,-hashtables,-arrays-and-strings/#fifth).

For more details on using Linq and possibly how to make it easier, the article [LINQ Through Powershell](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/06/07/linq-through-powershell.aspx) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I ran accross LINQ, when wanting to have a stable sort in PowerShell (stable: if property to sort by has the same value on two (or more) elements: preserve their order). Sort-Object has a -Stable-Switch, but only in PS 6.1+. Also, the Sort()-Implementations in the Generic Collections in .NET are not stable, so I came accross LINQ, where documentation says it's stable.

Here's my (Test-)Code:

```
# Getting a stable sort in PowerShell, using LINQs OrderBy

# Testdata
# Generate List to Order and insert Data there. o will be sequential Number (original Index), i will be Property to sort for (with duplicates)
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
foreach($i in 1..10000){
    $list.Add([PSCustomObject]@{o=$i;i=$i % 50})
}

# Sort Data
# Order Object by using LINQ. Note that OrderBy does not sort. It's using Delayed Evaluation, so it will sort only when GetEnumerator is called.
$propertyToSortBy = "i" # if wanting to sort by another property, set its name here
$scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create("param(`$x) `$x.$propertyToSortBy")
$resInter = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::OrderBy($list, [Func[object,object]]$scriptBlock )
# $resInter.GetEnumerator() | Out-Null

# $resInter is of Type System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<...>. We'll copy results to a new Generic List
$res = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
foreach($elem in $resInter.GetEnumerator()){
    $res.Add($elem)
}

# Validation
# Check Results. If PropertyToSort is the same as in previous record, but previous sequence-number is higher, than the Sort has not been stable
$propertyToSortBy = "i" ; $originalOrderProp = "o"
for($i = 1; $i -lt $res.Count ; $i++){
    if(($res[$i-1].$propertyToSortBy -eq $res[$i].$propertyToSortBy) -and ($res[$i-1].$originalOrderProp -gt $res[$i].$originalOrderProp)){
        Write-host "Error on line $i - Sort is not Stable! $($res[$i]), Previous: $($res[$i-1])"
    }
}
```