# Import-Csv of huge (13M Rows) filtered using Where-Object with 11k rows

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a huge csv file with about 13M rows and about 50 columns (File #1).  I have another file with about 11k rows that's a list of IP addresses (File #2), which is also one of the 50 columns in the first file.  How do I go about filtering File #1 so that the output contains only those rows where IP addresses from File #2 is found?

Here's what I've tried so far but it's been running for 12 hours and counting:

```
$IP = Get-Content -Path C:\Documents\File2.txt

Import-Csv C:\Documents\File1.csv | Where-Object {$_.IP -eq $IP} | Export-csv -Path C:\Documents\File3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `Get-Content` returns an array of strings. If you want to check if `$_.IP` is a value contained in that array, use `-in` instead of `-eq`, or do `Where-Object { $IP -contains $_.$IP }`. With such huge files, the code wil take its time though.. Maybe sorting the ip array from File2.txt helps speding it up a bit?

Comment: Could be worth taking a small sample of your files to ensure you get the logic working before working with that much data. Would be much quicker to determine if it is working or now.

Comment: +1 to @Theo 's comment. But also ... 13m x 11k = 143,000,000,000. That seems like it's reaching "crashing ps" levels... Maybe try something like this: https://www.spjeff.com/2017/06/02/powershell-split-csv-in-1000-line-batches/ break your csv into a few of more managable sizes. Maybe in the least you can run 13x 1m files. Then append them up after the fact. I can make a write up if you guys think it's a good idea.

Comment: He's "streaming" the csv, so he won't have it all in memory.  If he was using a foreach loop it would be different.  Doesn't mean this way will be fast, though.  :-)

Comment: I didn't realize that was how it worked @MikeShepard . I guess that's a major reason to keep everything in the pipeline rather than assigning it all the time?

Comment: Absolutely.  By piping the output, you don't have to materialize the entire collection and can process it a row at a time.

Answer (score 4):

You can make this script to run much faster:

- No need to use Import-Csv/Export-csv. Reading/Writng lines is
  sufficient and much faster
- $_.ip -in $IP is inefficient. Use
  hashtable for look ups (it will be about instant)
- Use .net tools
  rather than built in cmdlets

Below is the script with optimization I mentioned. Check commented lines before running

```
$inFile = "C:\stack\IpTables\Data.txt"
$IPfile =  "C:\stack\IpTables\IPs.txt"
$outFile = "C:\stack\IpTables\OutData.txt"
$ipIndexInData = 47 #index of IP address column in your data file

#build a hashtable for IP look up. 
$hash = @{}
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($IPfile) | foreach {$hash.Add($_, $true)}
# if IP values in your list are not unique then wrap $hash.Add() with try/catch


$fsIn = [System.IO.StreamReader]$inFile
$fsOut = [System.IO.StreamWriter]$outFile

$fsOut.WriteLine($fsIn.ReadLine()) # this will write first row with column names to out file. Comment it out if first row is data row

while (!$fsIn.EndOfStream) {

 $line = $fsIn.ReadLine()
 $row = $line -split ","

 if($hash[$row[$ipIndexInData].Trim('"')]) { # remove .Trim('"') if values in your data file are not quoted with "

    $fsOut.WriteLine($line)
 }

}
```

Comment: I would do the same : use system.io to read the file line by line and put the stuff in a hashtable since these are extremely fast with lookups.

Comment: Another .net tool to consider to improve performance: [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38360545/1701026)

Comment: This part `$row = $line -split ","` can break up badly if the data in the csv has commas inside quoted fields and since we don't know what is in the rest of the (50+) columns.. You need something like this: `$row = $line -split '\s*,\s*(?!(?<=(?:^|,)\s*"(?:[^"]|""|\\")*,\s*)(?:[^"]|""|\\")*"\s*(?:,|$))'`. This splits comma separated lists of optionally quoted strings. It handles quoted delimiters `","` and escaped quotes `\"`. Whitespace inside quotes is preserved, outside it is eaten.

Comment: Another way of looking up values quickly could be read the IP addresses into an Arraylist `$IPlist = [System.Collections.ArrayList](Get-Content "C:\Documents\File2.txt")` and then use the [ArrayList.BinarySearch Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.2) to find the value. This requires the list of IP addresses to be **sorted**. Don't know if it can compeat with using a Hashtable..