# It takes about 10 minutes to prepend header to a 100MB file

Tags: powershell

What is the fastest way to prepend header to a file?
100 megabytes file took
about 10 minutes
to prepend header to a file.
In java it take two seconds.

The example below is very slow:

```
$header = 'address;name'
Import-Csv .\myfile.csv -Header $header
```

**or**

```
Add-Content -path .\NewTest.csv -value "address;name"
$contents = Get-Content .\Test.csv
Add-Content -path .\NewTest.csv -value $contents
```

Comment: If you want to know which one is faster, why don't you try both and measure how long it takes? [`Measure-Command` is your friend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command)

Comment: If you want to do this using Import-Csv, you need to specify your csv uses the semi-colon as delimiter character using `-Delimiter ';'`

Comment: PowerShell differs from Java where it is optimized for streaming (pipeline usage). Generally, try to avoid to load the whole table into memory (do not assign it to a variable). Instead, directly pipe each object to the next cmdlet and eventually unload it from memory: `import-csv .\myfile.csv | foreach-object {` do your thing for each item`} | export-csv .\output.csv` (*please add more details of what you try to achieve*)

Comment: Bottom line, you can't justify the performance of PowerShell by taking the sum of some individual commands, [*as the performance of a complete (PowerShell) solution is supposed to be better than the sum of its parts*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026). In other words, it depends on what you want to do with each item with could potentially take longer than the overhead of loading and unloading a single item, see [Advocating native PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58357033/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\NewTest.csv' -Value "address;name"
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText('D:\Test\NewTest.csv', [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('D:\Test\Test.csv'))
```

You need to use full absolute paths for this

Comment: the last example removes the content of the file

Comment: @gavinnewsom you commented the wrong answer I'm afraid..

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET methods for working with file contents will usually be faster than the PowerShell cmdlets, because they have a lot of overhead etc. (Look at [this performance comparison](https://posh-able.com/2020/01/12/powershell-performance-part-2-reading-text-files/))

Here's a short and simple version:

```bsh
$path = (Get-Item .\myfile.csv).FullName
$contents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($path)
Set-Content -Path $path -Value "address;name"
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($path, $contents)
```

Here is another possible example, which will process one line at a time, and not read the entire text at once, so it's easier on your memory.

```bsh
# your original file
$instream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader "c:\test\myfile.csv"
# new temporary file
$outstream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter "c:\test\myfile2.csv"
# write the header
$outstream.WriteLine("address;name")
# write remaining contents
foreach ($line in $instream.ReadLine()) {
    $outstream.WriteLine($line)
}
$instream.Dispose()
$outstream.Dispose()

# replace the old file
Remove-Item "c:\test\myfile.csv"
Rename-Item "c:\test\myfile2.csv" "myfile.csv"
```