# Is there a syntax like JavaScript's Array.prototype.some() in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

While PowerShell has nice syntaxes like JavaScript's filter, map, reduce is there a syntax which is equivalent to `some`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [LINQ in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360545/can-linq-be-used-in-powershell) and then you can use [LINQ Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) which "Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition."