# Find the min element of Hashtable (Values are - DateTime) on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

There is a hashtable of view:
***key(string) - value (dateTime)***

Have to find the min value among Values (dateTime-s).
Can't find generic method to find such a value. The only way is smth like

```
$first_file_date = $dates_hash.Values | Measure-Object -Minimum -Maximum
Get-Date ($first_file_date);
```

Though visibly I get the result **($first_file_date)** the actual value casts to GenericObjectMeasureInfo type and I can't cast it back to DateTime to work further.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the datetime value or the corresponding string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you're interested in is stored in the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties of the object returned by `Measure-Object`:

```
$measurement = $dates_hash.Values | Measure-Object -Minimum -Maximum

# Minimum/oldest datetime value is stored here
$measurement.Minimum

# Maximum/newest datetime value is stored here
$measurement.Maximum
```

Use `ForEach-Object` or `Select-Object` if you want the raw value in a single pipeline:

```
$oldest = $dates_hash.Values | Measure-Object -Minimum | ForEach-Object -MemberName Minimum
# or 
$oldest = $dates_hash.Values | Measure-Object -Minimum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68470796/45375) with an alternative solution based on LINQ:

```sh
# Sample hashtable.
$hash = @{
  foo = (Get-Date)
  bar = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
}

# Note that the minimum is sought among the hash's *values* ([datetime] instances)
# The [datetime[] cast is required to find the appropriate generic overload.
[Linq.Enumerable]::Min([datetime[]] $hash.Values)
```

Use of [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) from PowerShell is generally cumbersome, unfortunately (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134048/45375)). [GitHub proposal #2226](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2226) proposes improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Sort-Object` for this:

```
$dates_hash = @{
    "a" = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(4)    
    "b" = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)    
    "c" = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(2)    
    "d" = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)    
    "e" = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(1)    
    "f" = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(6)    
    "g" = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(8)    
}

$first_file_date = $dates_hash.Values | Sort-Object | Select-Object -First 1
```

Or if you want the whole object:

```
$first_file = $dates_hash.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property "Value" | Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: `Sort-Object -Property Value` is a nice workaround for when you want to preserve the whole hashtable entry, but I wouldn't recommend `Sort-Object` for
determining a minimum / maximum in general, given that it involves a lot of unnecessary work and requires building up a sorted copy of the input collection in memory.
As an aside: PowerShell (Core) 7+ now allows you to use `-Top 1` with `Sort-Object` (instead of a separate `Select-Object -First 1` call).