# LINQ in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, linq

I am converting the application from C# to PowerShell. How can I call LINQ from PowerShell?

```
    [Data.DataTable]$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    [Data.DataColumn]$column = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn "Id", ([int])
    $dt.Columns.Add($column)
    
    # add data
    [Data.DataRow]$row = $dt.NewRow() # 
    $row["Id"] = 1
    $dt.Rows.Add($row)
    $row = $dt.NewRow() # 
    $row["Id"] = 2
    $dt.Rows.Add($row)
    
    # LINQ in C#: int[] results = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(d => d.Field("Id")).ToArray();
    [int[]]$results = [Linq.Enumerable]::Select($dt,[Func[int,int]]{ $args[0]})
    # Error: Cannot find an overload for "Select" and the argument count: "2"
    Write-Host $results
```

Comment: The answers from this link provide excellent guidance on how to use LINQ in PowerShell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360545/can-linq-be-used-in-powershell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can LINQ be used in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360545/can-linq-be-used-in-powershell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: For **general information** on the limitations of using LINQ from PowerShell, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360545/can-linq-be-used-in-powershell).

---

The problem is that **[`System.Linq.Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Select) is a *generic* method, and PowerShell has no way to specify types for the required *type parameters*, *up to  PowerShell 7.2.x***. To get this to work, *reflection* would have to be used, which is quite cumbersome (see bottom section).

However, you **can use a convenient PowerShell feature instead: [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)** allows you to access a property of interest directly on a *collection* (enumerable), and PowerShell will return the property values of *each element*:

```bash
[int[]] $results = $dt.Id  # same as: $dt.Rows.Id
$results # print -> array 1, 2
```

`$dt.Id` is effectively the same as: `$dt | ForEach-Object { $_.Id }`

---

For the sake of completeness (it isn't worth doing for this use case), here is the **reflection-based LINQ method**:

Note:

- **PowerShell (Core) 7.3+** now supports syntax similar to C#'s where you **specify a generic method's type arguments *explicitly*** - see the conceptual [about_Calling_Generic_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calling_Generic_Methods) help topic. The cumbersome reflection-based approach below is therefore only required in PowerShell (Core) 7.2- and Windows PowerShell.

```bash
# Using reflection, get the open definition of the relevant overload of the 
# static [Linq.Enumerable]::Select() method.
# ("Open" means: its generic type parameters aren't yet bound, i.e. aren't
# yet instantiated with concrete types.)
$selectMethod = [Linq.Enumerable].GetMethods().Where({ 
  $_.Name -eq 'Select' -and $_.GetParameters()[-1].ParameterType.Name -eq 'Func`2' 
}, 'First')

# Close the method with the types at hand and invoke it via reflection.
[int[]] $results = $selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod([Data.DataRow], [int]).Invoke(
  # No instance to operate on - the method is static.
  $null,
  # The arguments for the method, as an array.
  (
    [Data.DataRow[]] $dt.Rows, 
    [Func[Data.DataRow,int]] { $args[0].Id }
  )
)

# Output the result.
$results
```

Note that the above only shows how to instantiate the generic `.Select()` method.

To get an `` [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]] `` instance, a non-lazy *array* cast (`[System.Data.DataRow[]]`) was used in lieu of using [`System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable) - use of the latter too would require using the reflection-based approach.

It is evident from the above that **using LINQ from PowerShell is quite cumbersome, up to at least v7.3.1** - [GitHub issue #2226](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2226) proposes introducing better LINQ integration in the future.

For an - even more cumbersome - *generalization* of the LINQ solution that uses *dynamically* (indirectly) specified data types instead of data-type *literals* such as `[int]`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614483/45375) to your follow-up question.

Comment: I am trying to change hardcoded int to variable:
foreach($dtclmn in $df)
{
        $colName = $dtclmn.ColumnName
    [System.Type]$dtype = $dtclmn.DataType
  $results = $selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod([Data.DataRow], $dtype).Invoke($null,
    (
      [Data.DataRow[]] $dt.Rows, 
      [Func[Data.DataRow, $dtype]]{ $args[0].$colName }
    )
  )}
Error: Missing type name after '['.

Comment: @dburtsev, you can't use variables in type literals (`[...]`) - making that work would require more effort. Is there a reason you can't use _member enumeration_ (`$dt.$colName`)? It's syntactically much simpler, and you don't have to worry about types.

Comment: I am using member enumeration ($dt.$colName), it works. I just want to use a variable instead of hard-coded types. If this is not possible, I will write switch statement.