# Why can't I call IEnumerable.Sum() on an array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

In PowerShell, why can't I call the `Sum()` method on an `int[]`? For example:

```
[int[]]$arr = 1, 2, 3
$arr.Sum() # InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method named 'Sum'.
```

Yet, this method exists in .NET 3.5 and newer. So what's going on here?

Comment: You mean `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Sum($arr)` ?

Comment: In C# it does not get invoked as a static method. So there is still something unexplained here.

Comment: Ah this is the stupid crap around LINQ and its syntactic sugar, isn't it

Comment: I believe in PS we get the methods from LINQ as static, yes. Bible here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360545/can-linq-be-used-in-powershell

Comment: It's not LINQ specifically, it's PowerShell's general lack of support for _.NET extension methods_ (which LINQ heavily relies on) that requires explicit calls via the static methods of the LINQ types.

Comment: @mklement0 that's why I called it "stupid crap" lol; IMO a built in type normally shouldn't be using extension methods like this, although I understand why it was implemented this way for LINQ.

Comment: Yeah, since LINQ functionality is a "cross-cutting concern", applicable to a wide range of only abstractly related types, extension methods seem like the logical choice.